# How do I read Objective C methods

Tags: objective-c

I think the biggest problem I'm having with understanding programming is understanding what a particular method does. For example

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```

When I look at the above method I know that it returns a boolean and that the method receives the following.

1. NSTableView
2. NSTableColumn
3. NSInteger

However, I don't understand what I need to provide to use the method correctly.
Do I just return a boolean?

Answer (score 1):

This method will be called by the table (or something) on your delegate (the class you are implementing this method in) when the table needs to know if a certain row and column can be edited. You just need to return `YES` or `NO` to indicate if you want to let it be edited.

This is an example implementation:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    return NO;
}
```

This will mean the table can never be edited.

A more complex implementation like this would let only the first row be editable:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    if (rowIndex == 0)
        return YES;
    else 
        return NO;
    //This can be shortened to:
    //return rowIndex == 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you use return rowIndex == 1 if you are supposed to return YES or No?

Comment: `rowIndex == 1` is evaluated before the function returns.  the statement is either `true` (`YES`) or `false` (`NO`) and the value it evaluates to is the one thats returned

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to a saying: code tells you how, comments tell you why.

If you are writing a method, you need to know why you want the method and document it accordingly, a.k.a. comments. If you are overriding a method, then you would hope the producer of the method would document about what the method does.

If you're diving into iPhone development without a bit of programming background, you should at least read up the [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html). If you want to find out what a particular method does in your code, you can always right click the method name and choose "Find Text in Documentation" to read more about it.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row: should give you a clue that it is about editing rows and columns in a table view.  You could probably guess that, since it is returning a boolean it's called to determine with a table view should edit the supplied row of the supplied column.  However, that would just be a guess, so at this point (if I hadn't been using that method only yesterday and thus know exactly what it is for) I would start googling for it (or using Xcode search if I had access to Xcode).

A useful tip for Googling Cocoa documentation is to search only on site:developer.apple.com so we'll try [site:developer.apple.com tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:](http://www.google.co.uk/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:developer.apple.com+tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=C9FXTOefOomM0gSf1LXdCA).  The top hit in this case is [NSTableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) which is the one we want.